# Which is better in displaying empty shopping cart?

Tags: user-expectation, e-commerce, shopping-cart

Which is a better way in displaying customers' empty cart?

Suggest your products to them ? :

### [image: redmart.com empty cart]

Or just show that the cart is empty to the customer? :

[image: ipmart.com.my empty cart]

The first approach may help convert to sales, BUT only if customers do hover at the cart everytime they visit the page,

Second approach is common in most e-commerce site. Plus this is what customers will always expect when they hover/click on the cart. I believe this is what intuitive means, customers act on their own because it feels familiar, hence they might not hover/click at the cart frequently.

So which one should be used here?

Comment: Don't think there need to be suggestions to what a person might need to add in his cart. It's all subjective. Unless you have machine-learning enabled, I think option two is more common.

Comment: Shopping cart should not be visible if there is no product added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question I have is: **Why did the customer click on an empty shopping cart?** This is not part of the normal shopping flow.  Reasons I can think of:

- **The user doesn't understand how online shopping works.** In which case a more general message and link to help the user continue shopping would help.  I don't think recommendations of specific items add value, though, because you are unlikely to know what the user wants.  Therefore, these recommendations won't have much impact.  Plus, seeing a list of items here might be a bit confusing.
- **The user checked out recently and wants to review their order.**  In which case a link to past orders makes sense.
- **The user was working on an order but can't see it because they are not signed in.**  In which case, a sign in link might be what they need.

I would consider which of the above reasons might fit your case and tailor the message to the potential reasons and the current context.  For example:

> **Your shopping cart is empty**
>
> *Return to the store* to add items for your delivery slot.
>
> *View past orders.*

Or

> **Your shopping cart is empty**
>
> Please *select a delivery slot* to begin an order.
>
> *View past orders.*

Or

> **Your shopping cart is empty**
>
> Please *sign in* to begin shopping or continue an order.
>
> New to us?  *Create an account* to get started. *How ordering from us works.*

Comment: Why did I click an empty shopping cart? Because of poor UI design! This just happened to me. I was on a site that doesn't show the item count of an empty cart - without a nice Zero, how can I be sure my cart is really empty? In my case, I added my first item and then removed it after changing my mind. The interface didn't give me a warm fuzzy that the item was actually removed. In the store, I can see my basket is empty. A (and the only?) universal icon for an empty basket is the number Zero. Folks may be tempted by the word "Empty", but 0 requires 0 translation :)

Answer (score 0):

Randomly recommending things is not a good idea.

Option 1 - **No**.

Option 2 is the most used kind of shopping cart in these days. You may use that as well , which is quite normal.

But a plain message "your shopping cart is empty" is not the best UX you can have.

**Surprise the user**. Give user something to start with. You can give links to special offers. Or may be a link to what is special in your website ( based on what you sell ).

**The best thing**-
If you are using machine learning you can track the user history and recommend the most commonly browsed items to the user , based on his browsing history and patterns. ( this is a must do thing if you want build a decent e-commerce website ).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a combination.

#### Cart is Empty Message

> Message does need to be there to tell buyers that they have nothing in their cart. If you don't sow that message, it may confuse your buyers

#### Marketing Material

> Empty shopping cart page is a good place to provide an incentive to the shopper. If a buyer did end up on this page it could mean a couple of things:
>
> 1. User just removed last and final product from their cart for whatever reason
> 2. They forgot if they added a product their previously looked at into their cart
> 3. They just placed an order and wanted to review it again, or review past orders they've placed
>
> In either case you can re-capture their attention by offering meaningful information
>
> Take a look at [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com) and [Zappos](http://www.zappos.com/), both provide different incentives. You just have to make sure those incentives are not overpowering.